# Logical representation of a prime number

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Is it correct to represent a prime number like this?

$$\exists k \in \mathbb N,\, \exists n\in \mathbb N\, \Big((n\mid k) \land  (n=k \lor n=1)\Big)$$

Comment: @DonAnselmo, I definitely didn't know I had to do that... I kept clicking an arrow whenever I got an answer.

Comment: You seem to want a formula $\varphi(n)$ if and only if $n$ is prime. Your formula does not work. Depending on details of language, and what the variables range over, something like $\forall x\forall y((xy=n)\implies ((x=1)\lor (y=1)))$ will work.

Comment: You are looking for a predicate $\phi(n)$, a formula that is true when $k$ is prime and false when $k$ is not prime.  You can think of it as a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\{$True, False $\}$.  You don't want to quantify over $k$, because the value depends on $n$.  Joe Johnson 126 has given a good answer to that, but I wanted to show this part of the thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have claimed is that there are two natural numbers, $n$ and $k$, such that $n$ divides $k$ and $n=k$ or $n=1$.  This is true.  For instance, let $k=5$ and $n=1$.  What you want is that $k$ is prime if whenever $n$ divides $k$, $n$ must be $1$ or $k$.  That is, if $k$ is prime then
$$
\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \left((n\mid k)\Rightarrow (n=1)\vee (n=k)\right).
$$

Comment: But in a more general way that would be false...

If k were 6 and n = 3, then if 3|6 => n=1 or n=6 would be false!

I am looking for an expression that helps me determine if a number is a prime...

Comment: @Daniel If you let n=3 and k=6, then the statement would be false and thus 6 is not prime.

Comment: A nit:  this returns true for $k=1$, so you need to exclude that.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \Big\{ \ p \ \big | \ \forall x,y : \ xy=p \implies 1 < p < x+y \ \Big\}
\end{align*}

A number is prime iff it's greater than one and less than the sum of all of its factor pairs.